# CMSampleBufferRef in Swift 3 produce crash

Tags: ios, pointers, swift3

I have following Objective C interface in library:

```
@interface VideoSource : NSObject

- (void)setFilter:(void(^)(void *))filter;

@end
```

It was built with SDK 9.3. First argument in callback is CMSampleBufferRef.

Now I want to use that code in Xcode 8 with Swift 3 but in Swift 3 CMSampleBufferRef is not a pointer but class CMSampleBuffer. I tried several options but they all produce crash. Here is one of my attempts:

```
videoSource.setFilter { buffer in
    let p = buffer.load(as: UnsafeMutablePointer<CMSampleBuffer>.self)
    let sampleBuffer = p.pointee
}
```

How correct casting looks like?

Answer (score 0):

To make you approach work, change it as follows:

```
videoSource.setFilter { buffer in
    let sampleBuffer = buffer?.load(as: CMSampleBuffer.self)
}
```

`buffer` passed to the closure is a `void *` pointing to a `CMSampleBuffer` instance, so you should load it as such.

Comment: AFAIR result was the same - crash.